# Simplest binary tree insertion is not working

Tags: c++, binary-tree

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    int data;
    node *left;
    node *right;
    node(int value = 0);
};
node::node(int value){
    data = value;
    left = NULL;
    right = NULL;
}


class LinkedList{
    public:
        node *root;
        LinkedList();
        bool isEmpty();
        void insertInto(int value, node *key);
};

LinkedList::LinkedList(){
    root = NULL;
}

bool LinkedList::isEmpty(){
    if(root == NULL) return true;
} 

void LinkedList::insertInto(int value, node* root){
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        node *n = new node(value);
        root = n;
    }
    else if(value <= root->data){
        insertInto(value, root->left);
    }
    else if(value > root->data){
        insertInto(value,root->right);
    }
}


int main() {
    cout<<"I am gonna write the insertion of a binary tree"<<"\n";
    LinkedList sample;
    if(sample.isEmpty()) cout<<"THe tree is empty"<<endl; else cout<<"The tree is NOT empty"<<endl;
    sample.insertInto(5,sample.root);

    if(sample.isEmpty()) cout<<"THe tree is empty"<<endl; else cout<<"The tree is NOT empty"<<endl;



    return 1;
}
```

I have been working on this for quite some time, I dont seem to understand why the result is showing that the tree is empty even after adding the value 5. ALso please give tips on how I can improve. Thanks

Comment: Why do you call the data structure you're building a `LinkedList` when it's really a tree?

Comment: was working on linkedlists before this, so I went on with the flow, excuse it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the comments that I could make about the style/structure of the code you've posted:

```
    void LinkedList::insertInto(int value, node* root){
        if (root == NULL)
        {
            node *n = new node(value);
            root = n;
        }
```

You're not passing the `node* root` variable by reference here. Instead, you're changing a copy of the `node* root` to point to the new `node` object you constructed. If you want this code to actually change the value of the `sample.root` variable that you passed in from the main, you must pass `root` by reference.

```
    void LinkedList::insertInto(int value, node* &root){
```

Since `LinkedList::insertInto` is a member function anyway, why pass in root at all?
You have access to the member variable `root`, just use that instead. If you still want to be able to use it recursively, you could make a public function with just the value, and have that call a private version that also takes in a `node*` is a parameter.

Here are some coding style suggestions, since you asked for them:

Best coding practice dictates that you make member variables of your class private, and use public member functions to manipulate your class instead. This is for a variety of different reasons. One explanation is here:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143736/why-do-we-need-private-variables

So your class (and let's call it `BinaryTree` instead), would look something like this:

```
class BinaryTree{
    public:
        /*  functions  */
    private:
        node *root;
};
```

So instead of making the user of the class provide the root of the BinaryTree (which doesn't make sense since we know it anyway), we just ask them for the value to insert, and provide the root ourselves.

```
class BinaryTree{
    public:
        /*  other functions  */
        void insertInto(int value);
    private:
        void insertInto(int value, node* &n);
        node *root;
};

// Public version of the insertInto function
void insertInto(int value) {
    insertInto(value, root);
}

// Private helper function for insertInto
void insertInto(int value, node* &n) {
    if (n == NULL)
    {
        n = new node(value);
    }
    else if(value <= root->data){
        insertInto(value, root->left);
    }
    else if(value > root->data){
        insertInto(value,root->right);
    }
}

int main() {
    BinaryTree sample;
    sample.insertInto(5);
}
```

Comment: Yes, the changes done down the tree are not reflected back upstream.

Comment: Aaaaah, Its just that Ive had too much of theory and when im writing the code, i ignore some basic stuff.

Comment: also the isEmpty() function does not return on all paths, You should write either `return (root==NULL);` or `if(root==NULL) return true; else return false;`

Comment: Thanks a lot people. so the problem was basically that I should have passed the root node by reference.... and it is actually not necessary considering that its an in member function. Thanks @bobroxsox

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer solved your problem, please "accept" it by clicking the green check mark next to it :)

Comment: @bobroxsox is there any obvious comments that you can make about the strucuture of the code?

Comment: Sure, I'll add them to the end of my answer so I can format them nicely.